# New Automatic NuGet package resotore and NuGet.Config

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm migrating to new version of Automatic package restore as described in [docs](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore)

This documents says, that .nuget folder should be removed completely. Including NuGet.Config, that contained a property, we need:

```
<config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\..\commonNugetPackages" />
  </config>
```

So how one should specify path where packages should be restored?

**Update:**

Updating to 2.8 fixed the issue. I guess it was this [bug](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3521). Though it was fixed in 2.7.2 and I had 2.7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the NuGet.Config file since you are using it to change the default packages directory.

You can delete the NuGet.exe and NuGet.targets file from the .nuget directory and remove the Import in your project files that refers to NuGet.targets.

Comment: VisualStudio restores packages in the default location, if I do this. May be I'm missing something?

Comment: Move the NuGet.config file to the root of your solution. The .nuget folder was used by the target. You'll need to adjust your path to account for the change in location. See docs for how NuGet looks for the config file https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file

Comment: @Kiliman - Not sure that will make any difference. If the NuGet.Config file was working before in the .nuget directory then why would it stop working now? NuGet will check multiple directories for the NuGet.Config file starting in the .nuget directory, then going all the way back to the root directory. It could be that the NuGet.Config file has been changed or added since the solution was opened when the NuGet.Config file was added or modified since the solution will need to be reloaded for Visual Studio to pick this up. Another possibility is that the NuGet.Config file has invalid xml.

Comment: That's not really what the documentation says. The probing path starts at the drive root to the solution root or where nuget was run. The .nuget folder is nothing special. It's just where the Package Restore feature copied the nuget.exe file. That is why it loads the config file from there.

Comment: The page you linked to has the directories that Visual Studio checks and the first one checked is the .nuget directory. If the solution is at c:\a\b\c then the first directory checked is c:\a\b\c\.nuget so the .nuget directory is special.

Comment: @Kiliman I guess it was this bug: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3521   Though it was fixed in 2.7.2 and I had 2.7.4, updating to 2.8 fixed the issue.